# Как задать плавное исчезновение блока в этом js коде?

Tags: javascript

```
$('.header__bottom-img').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('.header__bottom').hide();
    })
```

Comment: Метки нет, но я предположу) мб это http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/ и https://habr.com/ru/articles/181179/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.header__bottom-img').on('click', function(){
    $('.header__bottom').fadeOut(2000); // через 2 секунды
})
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! То что надо